# Retrieve an elaborate manual about the ifconig

Tags: networking

I want to get ip address with  `ifconfig` and get

```
me@me:~$ ifconfig
enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 48:5b:39:68:79:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 889  bytes 74199 (74.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 889  bytes 74199 (74.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.231  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::e782:b8a7:7711:1b90  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:4b:d6:c5:c6:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54953  bytes 4365651 (4.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2628  bytes 352889 (352.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I cannot make sure to choose which one. inet or broadcats

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  Your wireless IP address on wlp3s0 device is 192.168.31.231.  If you send data to 192.168.31.255 (or the broadcast address) it will go to all devices on your segment of the network (ie. all devices 192.168.31.*) and does not relate only to your machine's port.  (*I'm not a networking guy, so my terminology may be imperfect sorry*)

Comment: Please notice that good old `ifconfig` is getting deprecated and replaced with `ip`. When you run **`ip a`** you get information similar to what you get with `ifconfig` (without options and parameters).

Comment: awesome, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @sudodus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that good old `ifconfig` is getting deprecated and replaced with `ip`.

When you run

```
ip a
```

you get information similar to what you get with

```
ifconfig  # without options and parameters
```

See `man ip` to get more details about available options, objects and commands.

---

According to your question, the IP address is `inet`**`192.168.31.231`** and you should see it also in the output of `ip a`.

Answer (score 1):

The ip address of yours is the inet, the broadcast is network reserved address for broadcast and the `subnet`.0 (in your case `192.168.31.0` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`) is the network identifier.

If you are interested to get more information about ip adress a good point to start is the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of this argument.